# Create multiple objects from JSON file

Tags: c#, json, object

I have a JSON file, that has many JSON objects:

```
[
"DIEM":
{
    "Name":["A"],
    "InRul":[]
},
"DOAN":
{
    "Name":["A","B"],
    "InRul":[]
},
"TAMGIAC":
{
    "Name":["A","B","C"],
    "InRul":[]
},
"TAMGIACVUONG":
{
    "Name":["A","B","C"],
    "InRul":[]
}
]
```

and, I have a class in C#:

```
class Content
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<string> InRul;
    }
```

How can I convert the JSON file above to objects in C#?

```
DIEM.Name //print Array [A]
DOAN.Name //print Array [A,B]
```

Thank so much!

Comment: If you post a valid Json, you may get some answers.. Paste your json in question to http://jsonlint.com/ and see the result

Comment: 2 things. First like EZI says, valid JSON. Second, if you did any searching on google about C# and JSON deserialising, then you would have seen JSON.NET. This needs to be closed due the user not doing any research at all.

Comment: Maybe the user didn't know to look for JSON deserialising and almost any google search for computer problems takes you to stackoverflow. If the question bothers you that much just vote to close it.